# Linux rdesktop ERROR recv Connection reset by peer

Tags: linux, remote-access, rdesktop

**PROBLEM**

I use for remote desktop connection script rdesktop. On some machines I get common error without any value.

What can I do after "Connection reset by peer" error?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

From time to time I forget this setting. The vast majority of it means "Turn off Remote Desktop with NLA".

Set on target "Microsoft Windows (WIN)"

1. run SystemPropertiesRemote.exe
2. deselect "Allow connections only from computers running Remote Desktop with NLA"
3. try to connect from linux client

**REF**

Thanks to Maccu Falchi

http://marcofalchi.blogspot.sk/2013/03/linux-rdesktop-windows-8-linux-error.html

Comment: Worked for me while trying to connect from Linux Mint client to Windows 2012 R2 Server.

Comment: Tried this on a windows 10 host. It does not work, at least at the time being. The freerdp-x11 works.

Comment: @minghua In my last experience with new instal "#win10 on aws" this was default disabled.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't have control over the server you are trying to connect to (or having a bit of chicken/egg situation), then use FreeRDP which supports NLA.

On Debian run

```
sudo apt-get install xfreerdp-x11
```

On Ubuntu run

```
sudo apt-get install freerdp-x11
```

On Fedora 22 run

```
sudo dnf install -y freerdp
```

Check [here](http://www.freerdp.com/) for more details

Comment: I needed to do `sudo apt-get install freerdp-x11` on ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Note, the executable is called `xfreerdp`.

Answer (score 2):

I've been dealing with the same issue.
The cursor is there - you just can't see it.

So, instead of grabbing some cursors from Windows and hacking your way around this - just use the "-C" flag to use your current custom color map.

e.g. rdesktop -C -u  -d  xx.xx.xx.xx

This fixed it just fine for me, and needed no other workarounds.

Comment: Thank you for valuable info about colors - but you know that article is about connection right? :-)

Comment: This worked.  However, `-u -d` appears to mean "log in as user `-d`".  Perhaps `-d` should be replaced with `username`.

Comment: This does not work on a windows 10 host at this moment. The freerdp does work.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in my case it was not the NLA authentication setting on the server. What has changed -- the operating system on the server was re-installed and so the fingerprint (or the host key) has changed. The `freerdp` on linux stored the previous fingerprint in a file under your home folder `~/.freerdp/known_hosts`.

The error comes from the fact that the server IP address is the same but the fingerprints don't match.

The solution is to clear or delete the `~/.freerdp/known_hosts` file on the linux guest.

Comment: I haven't encountered this error but good to know.